# Adding a Combobox to a Datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

So I'm developing a little program and I want to import datas from a SQL table to a datagridview, being one of the columns a ComboBox filled up from another table in the same database.

This is my current code:

```
Public Sub Load_black(Optional ByVal linhas As Integer = 20)
    i = 0
    black.Columns.Clear()
    black.Rows.Clear()
    black.Clear()
    ProdC.Open()
    Query = "SELECT * FROM [plano2] where familia like '%tpa%'ORDER BY ordem"
    myCMD = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Query, ProdC)
    myDRR = myCMD.ExecuteReader
    If myDRR.HasRows = True Then
        black.Columns.Add("Order", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Cut Style", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Cicles/cm", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Leght", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Colors", GetType(String))
        black.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String))
        While myDRR.Read And i < linhas
            black.Rows.Add(myDRR.Item("ordem").ToString, myDRR.Item("ref").ToString, myDRR.Item("design").ToString, myDRR.Item("tipodecorte").ToString, myDRR.Item("passagenscm").ToString, myDRR.Item("largura").ToString, myDRR.Item("numcores").ToString, myDRR.Item("dataentrada").ToString)
            str_pb_ref(i) = myDRR.Item("ref").ToString
            i = i + 1
        End While
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Table is empety.")
    End If
    myDRR.Close()
    ProdC.Close()
    grd_black.DataSource = black
End Sub
```

What I want to do is to add a new row with that combobox.

I already tried many ways but either I have the value in the database table either I have the combobox with the other table values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I have solved this problem before was to set up the columns for the datagridview in the form designer, setting the specific combobox columns.

then populate the combobox column options using a SELECT DISTINCT query.

you can hide the column headers until data is in the datagridview if you want beforehand.

its a bit of an ass changing column types in code as each column type is a different column type object
You have to make a new instance of

```
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
```

then add that to the datagridview

(First post - Any good?)

Comment: I tried it, but it dint work. I just got a blank colum. And no data from the table that i was trying to load.

Comment: ah i wasnt clear enough. which technique did you try?
you need to make a combobox column and get the options for the dropdown part using a select distinct query.
then put your data into that column from the query you already have